# Replace character in python string every even or odd occurrence

Tags: python, string, replace

I have the following python string:

```
strng='1.345 , 2.341 , 7.981 , 11.212 , 14.873 , 7.121...'
```

How can I remove all the ',' that their occurrence is odd, to get the following string:

```
strng='1.345  2.341 , 7.981  11.212 , 14.873 7.121,...'
```

(Removed "," )

I know to use replace but to replace all specific characters and not only odd or double.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution using list comprehension:

```
"".join ( [[",",""][i&1 if i else 1]+l for i, l in enumerate(strng.split(','))] )
```

The result of this piece of code is a string. Output:

```
"1.345  2.341 , 7.981  11.212 , 14.873  7.121..."
```

Answer (score 1):

A `zip()`-based solution.

Combines sublists made of pairs of items : one that starts from the beginning (index=0) and the second starting at the 2nd element (index=1).

```py
items = strng.replace(",", "").split()
strng = " , ".join([f"{x} {y}" for x, y in zip(items[::2],items[1::2])])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my step-by-step solution:

1. Split into list from `,`.
2. Append list and check for odd.
3. Simply update `res`

```
strng='1.345 , 2.341 , 7.981 , 11.212 , 14.873 , 7.121...'
newString = strng.split(',')
res = ""
for i in range(len(newString)):
    res+=newString[i]
    if i%2 != 0: res+=" , "
# Thanks to @areop-enap
# This code prevents trailing comma if you don't want.
if res[-2:-1] == ',': res = res[:-3] # checks if 2nd last string is and slices it
print(res)
```

Comment: I am not sure, but this might add a trailing comma to the output string if the amount of elements in the string is even.

Comment: Yes, but they wanted on every odd. You can simply check that and remove it.

Comment: Why do you want to create new variables for no reason?

Comment: @Majid it was just created so that the code is easy to understand!